# Vue Js not rendering few components in v-for

Tags: vuejs2

I am using v-for for  and then showing the components.  is rendering fine but inner element is missing. I am unable to understand. You can see two  columns  are empty but in the console three are 5 components rendered but showing only 3  components. Tell what may be the problem. any help will be appreciated 
[image: Screentshoot with console]

```
    <div v-for="(counterDate, index) in fulldate_array" >
    <template v-if="shift[officer.oid]">
        <shiftlayout v-for="(data,shiftKey) in shift[officer.oid][fulldate_array[index]]" :shift_data="data" :shiftKey="shiftKey" :date="singledate_array[index]" :fulldate="fulldate_array[index]" :width="shiftWidth"/>
    </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please also post your source code containing the v-for which is not working?

Comment: <div v-for="(counterDate, index) in fulldate_array" > 
 <template v-if="shift[officer.oid]">
   <shiftlayout   v-for="(data,shiftKey)  in shift[officer.oid][fulldate_array[index]]"  :shift_data="data" :shiftKey="shiftKey" :date="singledate_array[index]" :fulldate="fulldate_array[index]" :width="shiftWidth"></shiftlayout>
 </template>
</div>

Comment: I think You are not using `key` attribute, in the screenshot you can see all the component have the same key, so please put `key` as some unique id like index. and then also if it is still not working then provide a minimum working fiddle so the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: v-for="(data,shiftKey) i am using the shiftKey are you saying about this? or if something other then please help me how can i use the key @ashwinbande

Comment: @user3542190 he is referring to the key you should use with v-for's, shown in the Vuejs documentation [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key)

Comment: brettvd is correct!

Comment: Thank You i will try it

Comment: Is there another v-if inside shiftlayout component? and don't create anything in shiftlayout component because of your v-if? Also check your styles.

Comment: i have checked there is no v-if and still i stuck there i am unable to know what is the problem..